# Php curl missing content from page

Tags: php, curl

```
$url = "http://www.ksl.com/index.php?nid=231&sid=74268&cat=&search=&zip=&distance=&min_price=&max_price=&type=&category=&subcat=&sold=&city=&addisplay=%5BNOW-1HOURS+TO+NOW%5D&sort=1&userid=&markettype=sale&adsstate=&nocache=1&o_facetSelected=true&o_facetKey=ad+posted&o_facetVal=Last+Minute&viewSelect=list&viewNumResults=48&sort=1";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
```

This returns some of the page content. I think that because the page I am trying to curl uses `jquery` to insert the listings the curl executes before the jquery populates the page?

*Any ideas on how to get the full contents of the search curl?*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $url = 'http://www.ksl.com/index.php?nid=231&sid=74268&cat=&search=&zip=&distance=&min_price=&max_price=&type=&category=&subcat=&sold=&city=&addisplay=%5BNOW-1HOURS+TO+NOW%5D&sort=1&userid=&markettype=sale&adsstate=&nocache=1&o_facetSelected=true&o_facetKey=ad+posted&o_facetVal=Last+Minute&viewSelect=list&viewNumResults=48&sort=1';


/* gets the data from a URL */
function get_data($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}

$returned_content = get_data($url);

echo $returned_content;
```

Comment: with that code I am still getting the same results. The search results are completely missing.

Comment: You might have to set some cookie data and use that to access the site's search results.

Comment: I just tried: `function curlWithCookie($url, $proxy='', $userpass='') {
            
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, false); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
         
            if(!empty($proxy))
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
         
            if(!empty($userpass))
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $userpass);
         
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $result;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

No they are not getting the listings via jQuery, AJAX.  **There are no XHR requests.**

A view source shows the listings.

I just used this code to get

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
$url = 'http://www.ksl.com/index.php?nid=231&sid=74268&cat=&search=&zip=&distance=&min_price=&max_price=&type=&category=&subcat=&sold=&city=&addisplay=%5BNOW-1HOURS+TO+NOW%5D&sort=1&userid=&markettype=sale&adsstate=&nocache=1&o_facetSelected=true&o_facetKey=ad+posted&o_facetVal=Last+Minute&viewSelect=list&viewNumResults=48&sort=1';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
echo $data;
```

### The Result

Partial edited

```
Black Xbox 360 320gb Hard Drive Plus controllers and G...</a>
<span style="color: #555;">Magna,&nbsp;UT
&nbsp;|&nbsp; 1 Min
<div class="adDesc">
Selling because I got it used then only used it once, works fantastically and comes with lots of games plus 4 controllers and a keyboard for the contr&nbsp;
<a class="listlink" href="?nid=218&ad=34170943&cat=&lpid=&search=&ad_cid=7">more...</a>
<div class="priceBox">
<a href="?nid=218&ad=34170943&cat=&lpid=&search=&ad_cid=7">
<span >$450<span class="priceCents">00
<!-- <div class="adDays">1 Min -->
<!--<div class="adTime">Dec 31, 1969-->
<div class="detailBox">
Great PS4 Bundle</a>
<span style="color: #555;">Spanish Fork,&nbsp;UT
&nbsp;|&nbsp; 1 Min
Have here a great PS4 bundle with 6Games 1controller and 3months of PS Network. Still has the box. Text 801-633-1659&nbsp;
<span >$400<span class="priceCents">00
```